# ffmpeg - Max size of filter_script file

Tags: ffmpeg

I have been using the following command to successfully extract a list of frames from videos. I tried to use it to extract 12,227 frames and the command exits without generating any frames and error messages. I suspect there may be a limit on the size of the filter script file but can't seem to find what is the limit and how to increase it. Can anyone help please? Thank you.

`ffmpeg -i video.mp4 -filter_script:v Frames.txt -vsync 0 -video-%06d.jpg`

content of Frames.txt file is:

```
select='eq(n,70)
+eq(n,108)
+eq(n,183)
+eq(n,191)
+eq(n,197)
..... etc
+eq(n,18948)
'
```

Comment: Share full log.

Comment: @Gyan Here is full log:

https://drive.google.com/open?id=1uRivxjn4EhOkmWAGVnEfSadpidlpjX5V

Comment: The command works when I reduce the number of frames to ~8000.